English Scansion: Why Don't We Factor in Syllable Lengths and Pauses?
I hope people will forgive a beginner's question. Coming from a musical background, I'm very confused as to why syllable lengths aren't generally factored into analysis of rhythm in English prose and poetry.
Given the stress-timed nature of the language and how wildly syllables variable in length (ex: "flown" vs. "sat"), shouldn't these varying syllable lengths factor into a rhythmic analysis?
Example:
1. The JE-lly MAS-ter GLARED at MAX and CHARGED [him] a FINE.
2. The DIR-ty MAS-ter GLARED at MAX and CHARGED [him] a FINE.
3. The SCARRED MAS-ter GLARED at MAX and CHARGED [him] a FINE.

In all of these examples, my ears seem to hear a smoother rhythm (more evenly-timed beats) by disrupting the last/second last iamb by inserting "him". Yet an orthodox syllabic scansion should suggest that inserting "him" would be rhythmically disruptive to my understanding, when I actually think it's doing the opposite and reducing the rhythmic tension.
Also #1 seems to have more rhythmic tension between "jelly master" than #2 with "dirty master", even though the stressed/unstressed syllable patterns are the same. #3 also doesn't sound very rhythmically disruptive given how "scarred" is such a relatively long stressed syllable despite breaking the iambic meter.
Am I looking at this in a strange way or missing something very important? I've had some discussions with English poetry teachers on this subject and most responded by telling me that I'm conflating poetic rhythms with musical ones. Yet analyzing things more in terms of musical rhythm seems to help me come up with prose and poetry that sounds far more rhythmic to my ears, and better understand why certain poetry which others have written sound far more rhythmic and flow more smoothly than others.
Update:
This is the way I hear the first version with the omission of "him". There's a temptation for me to treat it like a tetrabeat rhythm (similar to 4/4 Western music) and briefly pause after "CHARGED" (maybe because it's such a long syllable; it almost wants to take the time of two syllables at least with the way I pronounce it).
1   2   3    4    1   2  3   4  1   2   3  4  1  2  3   4 
di  DA  di   DA   di- DA--   di DA- di  DA--     .. di  DA
The JE  lly  MAS  ter GLARED at MAX and CHARGED  .. a   FINE

It's where I see the insertion of "him" as rounding out that temptation to pause, as though to quantize "FINE" on an even beat and "a" on an odd one. Do you all hear it differently?
Update 2:
The suggestion to insert "John" also smooths things out to my pronunciation/ears, although I'm a bit confused as to how this now works in terms of syllabic scansion.
1: iamb  2: iamb  3: iamb    4: iamb  5:iamb      6: ???  7: iamb?
the-JE   lly-MAS  ter-GLARED at-MAX   and-CHARGED JOHN    a-FINE

I would have been tempted to interpret 6 and 7 as a cretic/amphimacer after the insertion of "John" rather than something which introduces a new foot.
With the preference for four feet per line, does adding this 7th foot help round things out with the pause at the end of the line? Even if it has 7 feet, it does seem to me like from a timing standpoint -- and after factoring in the pause at the end -- it rounds it out to eight major beats.
Update 3:
This example might be simpler and vary less in terms of individual proununciation:
1. The cat had sat on grass.
2. The cat had sat on a log.

#1 sounds more rhythmically tense to my ears even though it perfectly conforms to iambic trimeter. #2 doesn't conform nicely to a syllabic meter yet it seems much more rhythmic to speak aloud. I say #1 like:
1   2   3   4   5    6 
the CAT had SAT on GRASS
[GRASS is off-timed to the 6th beat; it's ahead of it]

... and #2 like:
1   2   3   4   5    6 
the CAT had SAT on a LOG
[LOG is timed well to the 6th beat]

Both are 6 beats (3 stressed) but against a steadily-timed metronome, "GRASS" is off-timed with the way I say it. It comes too early, making me want to pause if I want to smooth out the rhythm or if I don't pause, it just sounds off-beat. #2 seems to land "LOG" much more evenly in timing with "CAT" and "SAT".

I’m not sure this is really a question about linguistics, but just for the record, my ear disagrees with you. Inserting ‘him’ disrupts and destroys the rhythm and leads to a jarring non-verse, unless you allow it to fill a full foot (like ‘glared’ and ‘Max’), which is unnatural with a clitic pronoun like ‘him’. Had you added ‘John’ instead, it would have worked fine.

@JanusBahsJacquet I was a bit confused about the appropriate place to post. I was considering English Language & Usage but I got a message alerting me that it's for experts of the language, and I definitely don't qualify in that regard! On the rhythm, at least with the way I read it, there seems to want to be a pause after "charged": "I hear a tetrabeat pattern wanting to emerge: 1, 2, 3, 4: "The jelly master glared at Max and charged [paused] a fine." It's that pause that seems jarring to me unless we pronounce charged like "charg-ed" or really elongate the "a" with an /eɪ/ sound.

@JanusBahsJacquet I posted an update with how I tend to read it out loud. I asked my wife to read it as well and recorded it and played it over and over, and she also wants to naturally pause after "charged" although that's probably a very poor sample set since we both have fairly similar dialects and speech patterns.

@JanusBahsJacquet "John" also sounds better to me. "CHARGED JOHN a FINE". I just find a strong desire for an extra syllable sandwiched between "CHARGED" and "FINE" towards the end. Something about the stress timing seems a bit uneven to me otherwise towards the end.

I agree that an extra foot seems more natural – English tends to prefer four feet per line. But what’s missing is a whole foot, and weak words like ‘him’ don’t like to be stretched out into whole feet. That’s why I suggested using a name like ‘John’ instead. Alternatively, a regular iamb would work as well (“CHARGED the MAN a FINE”).

@JanusBahsJacquet I hope you'll bear with me but I posted a second update at the bottom expressing something I was confused about.

It's a fair question, but I'm not sure this is a "why" that can necessarily be answered. The vagaries of history led to this model of poetic meter catching on in English poetry. Similarly we ended up favoring rhyme and doing away with alliteration.

@Draconis Thank you! I'm wondering more from a practicality standpoint if we want to write poetry or lyrical prose (my goal one day). I find conformity to classical stress patterns creating rhythmic and pleasant sound patterns but only when the syllables don't vary wildly in length. For example, "Charged" takes me about as long or even slightly longer to say than "Jelly", even though the latter is two syllables and the former is one. So I often feel like I gain a better understanding of rhythm by treating one syllable like two beats sometimes, and sometimes two especially short syllables [...]

@Draconis [...] like one. That is to say, to avoid treating rhythm like there's a one-to-one mapping between syllables and rhythmic beats.

@NedStark Oh, well on that front, you have the poetic license to do anything you want! It would be breaking with English convention, but plenty of poets break with convention for one reason or another.

@Draconis I suppose I have this pipe dream for a foolproof guide to write things that sound nice.  That might already be hopelessly subjective. What I've found to my ears is that syllables with elastic phonetic sounds seem to be more rhythmically and phonetically forgiving. Like "dawn star" seems to sound nice in almost any context regardless of what gets stressed, since they're very elastic sounds that readers can easily stretch in a nice legato way to avoid abrupt pauses to even out stress timings. Meanwhile, more rigid and staccato sounds like "dog digs" seem rather tense in any context.

A syllable only has one length. But sometimes a two-syllable word can sound sort of like one in poetry. It's basically iambic heptameter.

Old English meter was much more flexible in terms of syllable counts, but was replaced by meters adopted from Romance languages. You might be interested in Gerard Manley Hopkins's "sprung rhythm".
